# Format JSON data into nested list using Lodash

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I am new to lodash, and I have difficulty in formatting data that will display on an expanded table. I have a response of data  from the server that looks like this:

```
[{Day: 1, ItemName: "Item1", Total: 1, Details: "Brand X", Quantity: 5, Part: "Part A"}]
```

And I wanted it to look like this:

```
[{
Day: 1,
ItemName: "Item1",
Total: 1,
ItemDetails: [{
     Details: "Brand X",
     Quantity: 5,
     ItemParts: [{
          Part: "Part A"
          }]
     }]
}]
```

I've used *.chain* and *.GroupBy* function and it displays on a table that shows the **Day, ItemName** and **Total** rows. Used *.map* function so when the user clicks the table row it expands and shows the **ItemDetails**.
But unfortunately i dont know how to display the last row or the third nested json data(which is **ItemParts**) that expands also when the user clicks the **ItemDetails**.

P.S. You can use any lodash function but please format the data to look like in the description above

P.S.S I only want to format JSON data response, I dont want to modify anything from my table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this without lodash,

```js
const arr = [{
  Day: 1,
  ItemName: "Item1",
  Total: 1,
  Details: "Brand X",
  Quantity: 5,
  Part: "Part A"
}]

const result = arr.map(x => ({
  Day: x.Day,
  ItemName: x.ItemName,
  Total: x.Total,
  ItemDetails: [{
    Details: x.Details,
    Quantity: x.Quantity,
    ItemParts: [{
      Part: x.Part
    }]
  }],
}))

console.log(result)
```